# Laser Harp Script errors with Arduino uno, any script bosses I your help is needed

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

For days now I've been trying to learn arduino scripts and after countless trial and errors I've managed to get it down to a few errors but I can't for the life of me figure it out and I'm sure its going to be something embarrassingly simple.

I've searched the net as much as i can but i still can't find where the problem is. 
I've seen how wonderful the good people of this site are and so i call upon your help.

ANY help will be amazing

Here is the full code...

```
#include <Stepper.h>

void setup() {

const int stepsPerRevolution = 400; // change this to fit the number of steps per revolution

// for your motor

// initialize the stepper library on pins 8 through 11:

Stepper beamsplitter(stepsPerRevolution, 8, 9, 10, 11);

int LaserState = LOW; // The variable that stores the state of the laser beam.

int sensor = 8 ; // Change this value to calibrate your harp's sensor

int delaylaser = 2000; // If you increase this, the laser will be brighter, but the harp will be less fluid

int motorspeed = 100; // This variable affects the speed, and fluidity of the harp.

int stepsize = 2; //size between beams

int LaserPin = 7; // Tell the arduino that the laser is on pin 7

int startupspeed = 3;

int pos = 0; // position of the laser

int beams = 12; // number of beams

int pitch;

void setup() {

pinMode(LaserPin, OUTPUT); // Setup for laser.

pinMode(6, OUTPUT); // Setup for status led.

digitalWrite(LaserPin, HIGH);

delay(1500);

//start sequence

beamsplitter.setSpeed(startupspeed);

beamsplitter.step((-beams * stepsize / 2)-1);

for (int x = 1; x < 60; x++) {

if (x<30) {

startupspeed = 103 - (100/pow(x, 1.0/4.5));

}

if (x>=30) {

startupspeed = 103 - (100/pow(x, 1.0/1.0));

}

beamsplitter.setSpeed(startupspeed);

for (int pos = beams; pos > 0; pos--) { // turn in other direction

beamsplitter.step(stepsize); // direction

}

for (int pos = 0; pos < beams; pos++) { // turn in other direction

beamsplitter.step(-stepsize); // direction

}



beamsplitter.setSpeed(motorspeed);

Serial.begin(31250);


}

}


void loop() {

for (pos = 1; pos < beams; pos++) { // turn in first direction

beamsplitter.step(stepsize); // switch position

//delayMicroseconds(delaymotor);

digitalWrite(LaserPin, HIGH); // turn on laser

delayMicroseconds(delaylaser / 2);

if ( (analogRead(0) > sensor ))\ // If the sensor gets a signalx

{

digitalWrite(6, HIGH); // Switch on status led.

noteOn(); // Play note 3

}

else if (analogRead(0) < sensor ) // If the sensor does not get a signal:

{

digitalWrite(6, LOW); // Switch off the status led.

noteOff(); // Stop playing note 2.

}

delayMicroseconds(delaylaser / 2);

digitalWrite(LaserPin, LOW); // Turn off the Laser.

}

beamsplitter.step(beams*stepsize);

}
```

And its giving me these errors...

```
sketch_oct07k.ino: In function 'void setup()':
sketch_oct07k.ino:33:14: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token
sketch_oct07k.ino:129:1: error: expected '}' at end of input
```

Anybody able to help a poor soul?

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicated some code.

There is a `void setup(){` at line 3 and 33. I assume its the second one at line 33 you need, otherwise all the vars are local to setup.

Comment: removed the void loop on line 3 
and it gives me this 


sketch_oct07k.ino: In function 'void loop()':
sketch_oct07k.ino:106:8: error: 'noteOn' was not declared in this scope
sketch_oct07k.ino:116:9: error: 'noteOff' was not declared in this scope

Thank you for your input sir!

Comment: It gave that to me too. You musn't have copied all the code. Can you see the functions in question defined anywhere in your sketch? However I answered your question for the errors you posted.